# Fetch data from table and save it in an XML file

Tags: mysql, xml

I am fetching a set of records from a mySQL table then storing it in an XML file as follows:

```
 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $deviceNumber=$rows['deviceid'];
 $videoNumber=$rows['videoid'];
 $paymentDate=$rows['paymentdate'];
 $paymentTime=$rows['timenow'];

 $xml = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlroot = $xml->createElement("xml");
 $payments = $xml->createElement("payments");
 $deviceid = $xml->createElement("deviceid", $deviceNumber);
 $payments->appendChild( $deviceid );
 $videonumber = $xml->createElement("videonumber");
 $videoid = $xml->createElement("videoid", $videoNumber);
 $payments->appendChild( $videoid );
 $paymentdate = $xml->createElement("paymentdate");
 $paiddate = $xml->createElement("paiddate", $paymentDate);
 $payments->appendChild( $paiddate );
 $paymenttime = $xml->createElement("paymenttime");
 $timenow = $xml->createElement("timenow", $paymentTime);
 $payments->appendChild( $timenow );
 $xmlroot->appendChild( $payments );
 $xml->appendChild( $xmlroot );

//Save the XML file
 $xml->save("userPaymentDetails.xml");
  }
```

The problem with the above method is, it only saves one record as follows:

```
 <xml>
 <payments>
 <deviceid>43CA3KZXYQGBK</deviceid>
 <videoid>1234567</videoid>
 <paiddate>2014-01-09</paiddate>
 <timenow>19:38:19</timenow>
 </payments>
 </xml>
```

I want to have multiple values in the XML file.
I want to achieve :

```
 <xml>
 <payments>
 <deviceid>43CA3KZXYQGBK</deviceid>
 <videoid>1234567</videoid>
 <paiddate>2014-01-09</paiddate>
 <timenow>19:38:19</timenow>
 </payments>
 <payments>
 <deviceid>76QL6DFBAQHJL</deviceid>
 <videoid>1348921</videoid>
 <paiddate>2014-01-10</paiddate>
 <timenow>10:20:12</timenow>
 </payments>     
 <payments>
 <deviceid>93CH3GHTYQGPM</deviceid>
 <videoid>890345</videoid>
 <paiddate>2014-01-15</paiddate>
 <timenow>14:32:40</timenow>
 </payments>
 </xml>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You create the XML file in the while loop so you overwrite the existing data every cycle. You should create the xml(XMLDocument and root element) outside of the loop and save it after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried keeping  $xml->save("userPaymentDetails.xml"); and  $xml = new DOMDocument(); out of the loop. If yes then what happens.

Comment: I had tried this, the problem is, it creates all the nodes, so i had to take `$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xmlroot = $xml->createElement("xml");` before the loop and `$xml->appendChild( $xmlroot );
  $xml->save("userPaymentDetails.xml");` after the loop. Thanks. Now it is working well.